# CSV file reading issue: with large amont of data

Tags: c, file, csv, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getfield(char* line, int num) {
    char* tok = line;
    char* result;
    if (line)
    {
        do
        {
            if (!--num)
            {
                tok = strchr(line, ',');
                if (tok == NULL)
                {
                    tok = &line[strlen(line)];
                }
                size_t fieldlen = tok - line;
                if (fieldlen)
                {
                    result = (char*)malloc(fieldlen+1);
                    result[fieldlen] = '\0';
                    strncpy(result, line, fieldlen);
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            tok = strchr(line, ',');
            line = tok + 1;
        } while (tok);
    }
    result = (char*)malloc(2);
    strcpy(result, "0");
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* stream = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    char line[1024];
    char *pstr;int num1,num2,num3;
    char* value1,value2,value3;

    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);

        value1=getfield(tmp, 1);
        value2=getfield(tmp, 2);
        value3=getfield(tmp, 3);

        num1 =strtol(value1,&pstr,10);
        num2 =strtol(value2,&pstr,10);
        num3 =strtol(value3,&pstr,10)
        free(value1); 
        free(value2); 
        free(value3);
        printf("Fields 1,2,3 would be 1=%d 2=%d 3=%d\n", num1,num2,num3);
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

above is my C code to read the file....

```
 :::: data.csv ::::
    10,34,30
    10,33,
    23,45,23
    25,,45
```

above is my file..

here my issue is I can call the function with "num" field. so that for reading of every line I suppose to call the function 3 times.. !! so the performance is too low for the large data files.. can someone help me that  I can call the  function at once and It will return  an array.. than I can easily store and print (e.g. for the first line  array[0]=10,array[1]=34,array[2]=30 )

Comment: Read all line and merge them as a string then use split(',') u will get an string[] storing all ur numbers

Comment: If you don't need the `line` later, you can just write a `\0` on the location of the comma and return an array of pointers into the `line` buffer. No need to `strncpy` anything.

Comment: @BuiAkinori This is C. There is no `split()`, and no `string[]`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs : I can't get you...any code change regarding that ?

Comment: and I can not change the csv file from the C code !!!!!

Comment: You don't need to put the `&pstr` in the `strtoll` call if you use separate strings, that parameter would be only useful if you parsed the string directly. So call `strtoll(s, NULL, 10)` or even use `atoi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could speed it up by creating a fast `split` function that will destroy your `line`  (not to mention the many lurking segmentation faults and memory leaks; this code has NO error checking or `free`ing of resources):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **split(char *line, char sep, int fields) {
  char **r = (char **)malloc(fields * sizeof(char*));

  int lptr = 0, fptr = 0;
  r[fptr++] = line;

  while (line[lptr]) {
    if (line[lptr] == sep) {
      line[lptr] = '\0';
      r[fptr] = &(line[lptr+1]);
      fptr++;
    }

    lptr++;
  }

  return r;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char line[] = "some,info,in a line";

  char **fields = split(line, ',', 3);

  printf("0:%s 1:%s 2:%s\n", fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);
}
```

result:

```
0:some 1:info 2:in a line
```

Comment: great.... just need a little bit help more.... as I suppose to convert it into  "integer" with strtol, here if it returns NULL strtool  gives "segfault" how can I make it returns 0 or any other value instead of NULL

Comment: Check if the value is `NULL` before calling `strtol`.

Comment: I see you answered on your own while I was off making coffee and testing.  Nice.  The pointer array makes random processing of the string arguments possible.  I took the malloc-free road, but pay for it in strlen() calls during the sequential scan.  I wonder which wins for 95711's problem?

Comment: @MikeHousky the `malloc` is needed because it is a function call. I need a way to return the results.

Comment: @user95711 because it will return the strol is ANY of the fields is not null (you are using `||`). Just use `atoi()`: `int f0 = fields[0]==NULL?0:atoi(fields[1])`

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yes, I know.  The intermediate string pointer array isn't needed though, if you convert the tokenized strings sequentially. The pointer array is nice for random processing of strings later, though. You have my up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run timing test on your code, but I'll bet a nickel that the problems is using malloc().  That is SLOW.

What Bart means is that a char[] array can contain multiple strings, back-to-back.  If you scan through the array as a single string once, changing all ',' characters to '\0', your last line would look like:

```
{ '2', '5', 0, 0, '4', '5', 0, ? rest of buffer }
   ^           ^   ^        !
```

The ^ carets below mark the positions where you'd record pointers to three strings.  As you can see, they are equivalent to separate strings of "25", "", "45" in separate arrays.  The ! below marks the 0 that ended the original string.  Nothing beyond that has any meaning.

All this depends on being able to modify the original string in-place, probably rendering it useless for any further processing (like printing out the offending line if an invalid field is detected).  However, you are already copying the original buffer for local use, so that shouldn't be a problem. I'd get rid of the malloc for that copy buffer too, by the way.

Code might look like:

```
while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
{
    char tmp[sizeof line]; /* this will save a malloc()/free() pair */
    char *tok, *fence, *pstr;
    char ch, *cp1=line, *cp2=tmp;

    while (0 != (ch = *cp1++))
        *cp2++ = (ch == ',') ? 0 : ch;

    fence = cp2; /* remember end of string */
    *fence = 0;  /* and terminate final string */
    tok = tmp;   /* point to first token */

    num1 =strtol(tok, &pstr, 10);
    if (tok < fence) tok += strlen(tok) + 1;

    num2 =strtol(tok,&pstr,10);
    if (tok < fence) tok += strlen(tok) + 1;

    num3 =strtol(tok,&pstr,10);

    printf("Fields 1,2,3 would be 1=%d 2=%d 3=%d\n", num1,num2,num3);
}
```

Obviously you don't need a 1K buffer to handle three values, so there will be a loop to pull out the values.  The if statement after the first two strtol() calls is your replacement for getfield(), which isn't needed any more.

After this is working, look at data validation.  Nothing in this (or in the original) will detect invalid numbers.

Comment: `malloc` isn't slow. The code is slow because its order is huge. The code runs in O(N*((M/2)^2)) with N being the lines and M the fields. Ow, and the strdup after reading a line also looks weird. The whole thing is very inefficient (as also said by @unwind).

Comment: The malloc/free combo has an instruction path of hundreds, if not thousands of instructions on a typical implementation. I'd guess free takes more because most implementations will want to validate the pointer being freed and not crash the heap.

Comment: I agree on that. But that is certainly not the problem of this code. As I said, his code is slow, because he processes every line (M/2)^2 times, which can be done once. If you **also** have a malloc/free cycle in each field processing, then it takes a LOT of time.